# Как создать навигацию по странице?

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу зделать навигацию по странице имеется база данных хочу чтобы выводилось попать заметок а потом на страничку 2 3 4 и так и дале не чтоб сразу 50 заметок на одну страницу
Подскажите урок или посоветуйтекак???Спасибо! 
Страничная навигация-вот что мне нужно!

Comment: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29
Что бы было примерно как на этом сайте цыфры 1 - 2 - 3
а не выводились все записи сразу на страницу

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tab LIMIT 0, 10
```

[Вот не плохая статейка по выводу данных частями](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/2003-08-19)

Comment: извините но я в Танке от этой стати))))

Answer (score 0):

[Урок на YouTube как сделать постраничную навигацию с помощью PHP и MySQL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W86QmL8E_rM)

и посмотрите тут - [Как сделать пагинацию на php?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/109901/mysql-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php)